# C# check if a reference is null - runtime binding error

Tags: c#, if-statement, nullreferenceexception

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

When I try to assign a JSON object to a var

```
var vrlvl = dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo.skill_level;
```

How do you check if a object is null before you assign it?

I've tried these, but it gives the same error

```
if (dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo.skill_level != null)

if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo.skill_level))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to check a few levels up too:

```
if (dataFirst && dataFirst.payload && dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches && dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo && dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo.skill_level)
{
    var vrlvl = dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo.skill_level;
}
```

Edit: try this:

```
if (dataFirst != null && dataFirst.payload != null && dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches != null && dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo != null && dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo.skill_level != null)
{
    var vrlvl = dataFirst.payload.last_quick_matches.csgo.skill_level;
}
```

Comment: This returns the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: I was thinking in JavaScript - I made an edit that should work now...

Comment: The conditional statement can be shortened to `if (dataFirst?.payload?.last_quick_matches?.csgo?.skill_level != null)`.